# SSIS package can be run using "Execute Package Utility" but not in an agent job?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I imported a SSIS package, which pump a local Sql server table to a remote Sql server, into MSDB SSIS storage and I can execute the package by right clicking and executing. However, it raises following error when I tried to run it in an agent job. The destination connection uses an Sql login on the remote Sql server.

> Executed as user: Domain\MyLogin. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.0.4000.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-2005. All rights reserved.    Started:  6:04:09 PM  Error: 2013-05-01 18:04:09.75     Code: 0xC0016016     Source:       Description: Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Password" with error 0x8009000B "Key not valid for use in specified state.". You may not be authorized to access this information. This error occurs when there is a cryptographic error. Verify that the correct key is available.  End Error  Error: 2013-05-01 18:04:10.31     Code: 0xC0202009     Source: Reload_Table Connection manager "DestinationConnectionOLEDB"     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E4D  Description: "Login failed for user 'QA_USERS'.".  End Error  Error: 2013-05-01 18:04:10.31     Code: 0xC020801C     Source: Data Flow Task 1 Destination - tmp_test [34]     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "DestinationConnectionOLEDB" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.  End Error  Error: 2013-05-01 18:04:10.31     Code: 0xC0047017     Source: Data Flow Task 1 SSIS.Pipeline     Description: component "Destination" (34) failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.  End Error  Error: 2013-05-01 18:04:10.31     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: Data Flow Task 1 SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more component failed validation.  End Error  Error: 2013-05-01 18:04:10.31     Code: 0xC0024107     Source: Data Flow Task 1      Description: There were errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  6:04:09 PM  Finished: 6:04:10 PM  Elapsed:  0.766 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me before, and it is because you are using windows authentication in the SSIS package, that means that when you run it, it will use your Windows user, when you run it from the server it will use the server's user.

In other words, avoid using windows authentication in your SSIS and change it to a regular SQL user, that will fix your issues.

Comment: I would suggest rather than not using Windows Authentication, instead actually learn about it. Not using windows authentication means you now have to go and learn about package protection levels which is even more confusing for a beginner.